# regex for address in span tags

Tags: regex

I need to extract an address which will change on every new page from a sample like this.  So I need a regex to extract 100 E Faith Ter from the following html code snippet.

```
<span style="..." class="addr">100 E Faith Ter<br>
    <span class="locality">Maitland</span>,
    <span class="region">FL</span>
    <span class="postal-code">32751</span>
</span>
```

I am using Javascript.

Comment: Why not use a regular html parser to extract this information?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify a language, and regular expressions are pretty language agnostic, but they differ in specifying how they deal with multiple lines. In javascript: `/^.*$/m` selects the first line.

Having updated your question to be full HTML instead of raw text, you can use:

```
^\<.+?\>(.+?)\<br\>$
```

and retrieve the first parenthesized submatch (be sure you use the multiline option)

Comment: This would be better as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

[The Pony He Comes!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

A regex is not necessary for the whole thing. Instead, just use strip all HTML tags - if you're using PHP, [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip-tags) does this nicely, otherwise you can regex it replacing `<[^>]+>` with an empty string. You should get the plain text of the address. You can then split this on its separate lines.

Or you could just be this guy:

[image: xkcd]

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using Javascript.  Is there a similar mechanism to strip tags in there.

Comment: Use the regex alternative I gave you.